# cannot get kafka sample producer / consumer to run

Tags: linux, apache-kafka

I finally managed to setup zookeeper and kafka 0.7.2 on a CentOS box and tried to run the console-producer.sh sample.

```
   [root@syslogtest bin]# bash kafka-console-producer.sh
   Error: could not find or load main class kafka.producer.ConsoleProducer
```

apart from the http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart.html guide is there any other links someone could suggest to learn kafka. Just setting up I had to find other resources than this site which is turning out to be frustrating.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are starting to learn Kafka, you might want to consider learning version 0.8 as there are several important updates like replication. (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Changes+in+Kafka+0.8)

You can check https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Index for concrete examples on setting up consumer and producer.

Finally there's an active community for Kafka at http://grokbase.com/g/kafka/

Comment: Kafka 0.8 still is not a production ready: you will stumble some subtile bugs, you will have to somehow manage api artifacts and so on.